# Is React Native really used in Facebook and Instagram Android/iOS app?

Tags: react-native

I'm just discovered react native and nativescript.They are similar.But in react native showcase , you can see Instagram and Facebook android/ios app.

Is React Native really used in Facebook and Instagram Android/iOS app ?

Or , is react native used partially on Facebook and Instagram ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you about Instagram, but an earlier version (I haven't looked at a recent version) of the Facebook app was using a very early version of React Native for the advertising system.  Technically it qualifies as using it; but the majority of the android app was Native, and not using React Native.